# Angular 6 - LESS animation not working after deploy

Tags: css, angular, typescript, less, webdeploy

Good Morning everyone!
I have a problem with LESS animation. I'm pushing my app on the server after ng build --prod, then browsers can't see the CSS animation. It's working on the localhost, but not working after deploy and I don't know why :(

localhost:
[image: localhost]

my website: [image: website]

angular.json:

```
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/website",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.less"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

and my keyframes mixins:

```
     .keyframes(rollimg, {
              0% {
                right: -300px;
                opacity: 0;
              }
              50% {
                right: 0;
                opacity: 0.8;
              }
              60% {
              right: -40px;
              }
              100% {
                right: 0;
                opacity: 1;
              }
              });
                  .keyframes (scrollup, {
                          0% {
                            top: 0;}
                        50% {
                          top: 10px;
                        }
                          100% {
                            top: 0;
                          }
                        });
```

Neither animations not works, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ok my fault :( My .animation Mixin was incorrect :( problem solved